# Exception is already defined in this compilation unit import java.lang.Exception;

Tags: java

Trying to create custom exception am extending the Exception class, which is resulting in the error

error: Exception is already defined in this compilation unit

If you remove the import statement --> import java.lang.Exception

then new set of errors is coming below

--------------------Configuration: --------------------

E:\ArjunJava\Exception.java:29: error: incompatible types: MyException cannot be converted to Throwable

```
throw new MyException("Array size is less than what you are referencing");
    ^
```

E:\ArjunJava\Exception.java:35: error: incompatible types: MyException cannot be converted to Throwable

```
    catch(MyException me)
          ^
```

E:\ArjunJava\Exception.java:37: error: cannot find symbol

```
System.out.println("Exception caught "+me.getMessage()); 
symbol:   method getMessage() location: variable me of type MyException
```

E:\ArjunJava\Exception.java:15: error: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;

```
super(message);
    ^
required: no arguments
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

4 errors

Process completed.

```
import java.lang.Exception;

class MyException extends Exception {
   MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
   }
}

public class Exception {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      // array of size 4. 
      int[] arr = new int[4];//Referring 5th Element 
      try {
        int i = arr[4]; // this statement causes an exception 
        throw new MyException("Referring to element more than Array size");
      } 
      catch(MyException me) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : "+me.getMessage()); 
      }
   } 
}
```

Output:

Exception caught : Referring to element more than Array size

Comment: You can't have two top level classes in one file.

Comment: There are several things wrong, including 1) Declaring your own class "Exception".  In this case, all you need to do is rename the source file "MyException.java", and refactor everything into one class: "MyExcpetion".  2) You *should* get an "out of bounds" error trying to access index 4 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4): the 5th element of a 4-element array.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You can -- but only one can be public, and if there's a public class, the file needs to be named after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're defining a class named "Exception" and trying to use an existing class -- a built-in class -- named "java.lang.Exception" in the same program. You have to do this very carefully, by using the full name "java.lang.Exception" for the built-in class when you refer to it:

```
class MyException extends java.lang.Exception
```

If you remove the 'import' and change the declaration of MyException to the above, then your class will compile. Another way to dea with this would be to name your program class something besides "Exception", like "ExceptionTest".

Unfortunately, it still won't behave quite as you want; the line labelled "this statement causes an exception" will indeed throw an exception before your "throw" statement gets a chance to execute. But now that your code compiles, you can experiment for yourself.

Comment: Yes the code compiled, the statement precedes my throw statement

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you have `main()` defined inside the class `Exception` which is already used by Java and imported by default. Change the name of the class from `Exception` to anything else and your code should work fine. The other way of approaching to the problem, if you do not want to change the name of the class would be use fully qualified name for `Exception` as shown below:

```
class MyException extends java.lang.Exception {

}
```

Again, you **do not need to explicitly have the import statement**